# ContextMenu onItemClick (ListView)

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I need a context menu to be shown when user clicks on item in listview (not long tap). How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way it probably to do it like Reflog said.

But you could try it like this:

1. enable long click though and you need to call registerForContextMenu(list) for the list.
2. call the performLongClick() in the OnItemClickListener
3. override the onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) function, there just add the menu items by menu.add().

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use AlertDialog.Builder with 'options' parameter. It emulates the context menu.

Comment: can you detail a bit more?